# UICollectioView: wrong content offset after adding cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

**I creating cycling UICollectionView (so it's impossible for user to scroll to the end, because when he scrolls to prev row, I remove not proper rows from the end to insert them to the beginning of UICollectionView.**

In my UICollectioView I always have 11 cells. The UICollectionViewCell has the same bounds as UICollectionView.

**The issue**: For example I scrolled content to the indexPath with row = 2. If I add 2 cell to the beginning and remove 2 cell from the end, I want to see the same cell, but it scrolls to the second row (the row I saw before), but I don't want smth to be scrolling, I want to insert 2 rows without any animation, so user should see the 4th row, but it thinks that it's the 2nd row)

Here is the code:

```
let numberOfRowInCollectionView = collectionView_help_getNumberOfRowsInCollectionView()
                collectionViewMain.performBatchUpdates({ [weak self] in

                    if self == nil {
                        return
                    }

                    let currentRowOffset = 2
                    let numberOfRowsToAddFromLeft = currentRowOffset // number of rows we need to add or remove from left
                    var array_indexPathToAdd = [NSIndexPath]()
                    var array_indexPathToRemove = [NSIndexPath]()
                    for i in 0..<numberOfRowsToAddFromLeft {
                            array_indexPathToAdd.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0))
                            array_indexPathToRemove.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: numberOfRowInCollectionView - 1 - i, inSection: 0))
                        }

                    self?.collectionViewMain.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(array_indexPathToAdd)
                    self?.collectionViewMain.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(array_indexPathToRemove)

                    self!.selectedRow += currentRowOffset

                    }, completion: {  (finished) in
                        completionBlock?()
                })
```

I tried to add :

```
// select new row
                        let selectedIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: self!.selectedRow, inSection: 0)
                        self!.collectionViewMain.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath, atScrollPosition: .CenteredHorizontally, animated: false)
```

And after that it selects proper new row (now it = 4), but it does it with animation so user sees that smth is happening .

But I want just to add 2 cell at the beginning and user shouldn't see that smth is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this source code to implement this cycling UICollectionView [Git](https://github.com/RungeZhai/SeamlessCyclicScrollView)

The idea is not to use deleting and inserting cells in UICollectionView, but just have additional 0 (with data of last object in array) and last (with data of 0 object in array) rows and to set content offset without animation.